# .NET Framework 4.5.2.: Multiple custom attributes of the same type found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I've run the app on my desktop and it works. Then I've published it on an IIS "QA" server and it works too. But now that I've published the built app into a "Live" IIS server I'm getting this exception message.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

This is the whole error description:

```
[AmbiguousMatchException: Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.]
   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) +119
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.get_FrameworkDescription() +127
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +243
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +173
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ClientDocumentHelper.CreateClientDocument(String applicationName) +76
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer..ctor(String applicationName, IReadOnlyList`1 compressors) +20
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnectionFactory..ctor(ConnectionSettings settings, IStreamFactory streamFactory, IEventSubscriber eventSubscriber) +186
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ClusterBuilder.CreateConnectionPoolFactory() +62
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ClusterBuilder.CreateServerFactory() +21
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ClusterBuilder.CreateClusterFactory() +18
   MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.CreateCluster(ClusterKey clusterKey) +549
   MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.GetOrCreateCluster(ClusterKey clusterKey) +113
   MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(MongoClientSettings settings) +118
   SOMSightRepositories.LanguageMongoRepository..ctor(IMongoProvider pMongoProvider) +207
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +315
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +335
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +390
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +130
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +203
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +335
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +390
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +130
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +390
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +335
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +390
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +130
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +1538
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +335
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +390
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +130
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +214
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +335
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +390
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +451
```

[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "SOMSight.Controllers.HomeController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor SOMSightRepositories.LanguageMongoRepository(ISOMSightRepositories.Utils.IMongoProvider pMongoProvider).

### Exception is: AmbiguousMatchException - Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving SOMSight.Controllers.HomeController,(none)
  Resolving parameter "pAssessmentService" of constructor SOMSight.Controllers.HomeController(ISOMSightServices.IAssessmentService pAssessmentService, ISOMSightServices.IPayPalPaymentService pPayPalPaymentService, ISOMSightServices.IPayPalSubscriptionsService pPayPalSubscriptionsService, ISOMSightServices.IPayPalConfigurationService pPayPalConfigurationService, ISOMSightServices.ITenantService pTenantService, ISOMSightServices.ISOMSightPlanModularityService pSOMSightPlanModularityService, ISOMSightServices.ISessionState pSessionState, ISOMSightServices.Files.IFileManagerLocalStorageService pFileManagerLocalStorageService, ISOMSightServices.ICRMServices pCRMServices)
    Resolving SOMSightServices.AssessmenstService,(none) (mapped from ISOMSightServices.IAssessmentService, (none))
    Resolving parameter "pTranslatorUtility" of constructor SOMSightServices.AssessmenstService(ISOMSightRepositories.Common.IUnitOfWork pUnitOfWork, ISOMSightRepositories.IAssessmentSummaryRepository pAssessmentSummeryRepository, ISOMSightRepositories.IAssessmentSummaryTempRepository pAssessmentSummeryTempRepository, ISOMSightRepositories.IAssessmentQuestionTempRepository pAssessmentQuestionTempRepository, ISOMSightRepositories.IAssessmentQuestionRepository pAssessmentQuestionRepository, ISOMSightServices.Users.IUserService pUserService, SOMSightModels.Utils.IConfigUtility pConfigUtility, SOMSightModels.Utils.ITranslatorUtility pTranslatorUtility, ISOMSightServices.IEmailService pEmailService, ISOMSightRepositories.IAssessmentTypeRepository pAssessmentTypeRepository, ISOMSightRepositories.IMaturityLevelRepository pMaturityLevelRepository, ISOMSightServices.IAssessmentQuestionService pAssessmentQuestionService, ISOMSightServices.Assessments.IAssessmentFileService pAssessmentFileService, ISOMSightRepositories.IModuleRepository pModuleRepository, ISOMSightRepositories.ISOMSightOfferedModuleRepository pOfferedModuleRespository, ISOMSightRepositories.IRecommendationRepository pRecommendationRepository)
      Resolving SOMSight.Utils.TranslatorUtility,(none) (mapped from SOMSightModels.Utils.ITranslatorUtility, (none))
      Resolving parameter "languageMongoService" of constructor SOMSight.Utils.TranslatorUtility(ISOMSightServices.ISessionState sessionState, ISOMSightServices.ILanguageMongoService languageMongoService, ISOMSightServices.ITranslatorMongoService translatorMongoService)
        Resolving SOMSightServices.LanguageMongoService,(none) (mapped from ISOMSightServices.ILanguageMongoService, (none))
        Resolving parameter "pITranslatorMongoRepository" of constructor SOMSightServices.LanguageMongoService(ISOMSightRepositories.ILanguageMongoRepository pITranslatorMongoRepository)
          Resolving SOMSightRepositories.LanguageMongoRepository,(none) (mapped from ISOMSightRepositories.ILanguageMongoRepository, (none))
          Calling constructor SOMSightRepositories.LanguageMongoRepository(ISOMSightRepositories.Utils.IMongoProvider pMongoProvider)
]
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +551
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +61

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'SOMSight.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +162
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +258
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +119
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +97
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1122
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +131

Answer (score 0):

See this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/1542) for ways to resolve it.

It appears to be a known issue with application insights.

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306984/azure-search-multiple-custom-attributes-of-the-same-type-found)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue pertaining Application Insights. The issue is officially tracked [here](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/1542).

Some possible ways (be sure to check the link for an exhaustive list) to solve it include:

- Downgrading Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime to v2.3.2.
- Catch and ignore the exception with a `try` and an empty `catch` block.
- Disable Application Insights Azure WebSite extension or StatusMonitor.
- Have a new ASP.NET project which does not use Application Insights and do not enable sending telemetry when deploying the cloud service.
- Update the Application Insights package.